# how compare localdatetime with current date including hours in java

Tags: java, localdate, localdatetime

My Local date Time(Shipping) in the format like "2023-01-11T01:25:59"

I need to compare with current time do the below conditions

1. If both are in same date and Shipping hour more than current hour
2. Shipping Date equals next Current date ( In this case Shipping Date = 2023-01-11 == Current date + 1 day

I did this but it's not working with hours

```
LocalDateTime shippingdate= (calling funtion)
System.out.println("shippingdate "+shippingdate);  //2023-01-11T01:25:59 

LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println("currentTime "+currentDateTime);   //2023-01-10T03:42:52.574994

int diff = shippingdate.compareTo(currentDateTime);

if (diff==1) {
}

if (diff > 1) {
}


LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Comment: By "more than current hour", do you mean more than 1 hour, or the hour component just has to be more? In other words, would shipping time being 00:59:59 and the current time being 01:00:00 fulfil the condition? The same goes for the second condition. Does it need to be 24 hours more, or are you only looking at the calendar day?

Comment: The LocalDateTime class has getHour(), getMinute(), and getSecond() methods you can use it for comparing the time fields, you can have a look at the LocalDateTime api here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Comment: more than 1 hour

Comment: If shipping date and current date is same and Shipping Time 8 PM and Current Time 7PM  then condition true :  Deliver Today at 8 PM

Comment: If shipping date equals to tomorrow current date is same and Shipping Time 8 PM and Current Time 7PM then. : Deliver Tomorrow 8PM

Comment: Maybe 1) `current.toLocalDate().isEqual(shipping.toLocalDate()) && shipping.getHour() > current.getHour()`?

Comment: And 2) `current.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).isEqual(shipping.toLocalDate())`?

Comment: For 1) the last part of the condition is `shippingdate.isAfter(currentDateTime.plusHours(1))`.  I think. Also @Slaw

Comment: `compareTo()` only tells you which date-time is after which one, not by how much.

Comment: Is your shipping input meant to represent a date and time as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds? Your code implies that, but you should say so explicitly.

Comment: In addition to what @BasilBourque says the question of "same date" depends heavily on time zone. You may not want to use UTC here?? Would the user expect it to use their time zone?

Comment: You should be editing your Question, rewriting to make it clear and specific.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

One problem is your inappropriate use of the `LocalDateTime` class. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or office from UTC. So that class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Yet you are trying to track moments, apparently.

If handed a date and time only, parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2023-01-11T01:25:59" ) ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

But if you are certain that date and time was meant to represent a moment as seen with an offset of zero, immediately convert to an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Meanwhile, educate the publisher of your input data about their failure to communicate all three pieces of vital info (date, time, *and* offset/zone).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

The idea here is to “tell the truth”. If the intention is a date with time as seen in UTC, then our code should represent a date with time as seen in UTC.

Apparently you want to compare this date-time in UTC against the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

Your primary concern is the date.

```
LocalDate shippingDate = odt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;

if ( shippingDate.isBefore( today ) { … is past }
else if ( shippingDate.isEqual( today ) { … is today }
else if ( shippingDate.isEqual( tomorrow ) { … is tomorrow }
else if ( shippingDate.isAfter( tomorrow ) { … is future }
else { … throw exception because we should never reach this point }
```

## `OffsetDateTime#getHour`

Your secondary concern was apparently that you want to know, if today, is the target hour the same as the current hour. Your writing is not at all clear on this point, but that is my guess.

So add a nested test within the “is equal to today” test branch above.

```
if( odt.getHour() == now.getHour() ) { … same clock hour }
```

Or perhaps you want to test for a later, future hour.

```
if( odt.getHour() > now.getHour() ) { … later, future hour }
```